# Selecting and outputting results from DB with an array

Tags: array, select

I have always had issues with arrays. I can never seem to get them to work correctly.

Could someone advise me.

I want to make a selection from the database, use that in another selection and then load the results into an array and use a for each loop to print the data from each one. Could anyone advise how to do this.

```
$extractmonth= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT month FROM `pictureofthemonthextract`");

$extractyear= $wpdb->get_var("SELECT year FROM `pictureofthemonthextract`");

$allresults= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT imageurl, userid, caption, month, year, width, height, order FROM `pictureofthemonth` where month = \"$extractmonth\" and year = \"$extractyear\"");
```

So far I have the selection above, but I want the results to load into an array and a for each loop to print them.